# Loop Joints in Multi Body Tree

Tags: drake

I know that the sdf format supports closed kinematic chains, but does drake's multibody tree sdf parser handle these correctly at the moment? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not yet, but I spoke to Alejandro on our team; I've filed an issue here:
https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/9566
He mentioned that it's on his plate for upcoming features.

Thanks!